# elasticsearch query string dont search by word part

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I'm sending this request

```
curl -XGET 'host/process_test_3/14/_search' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "\"*cor interface*\"",
      "fields" : ["title", "obj_id"]
    }
  }
}'
```

And I'm getting correct result

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 5.421598,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "process_test_3",
        "_type": "14",
        "_id": "141_dashboard_14",
        "_score": 5.421598,
        "_source": {
          "obj_type": "dashboard",
          "obj_id": "141",
          "title": "Cor Interface Monitoring"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I want to search by word part, as example

```
curl -XGET 'host/process_test_3/14/_search' -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "\"*cor inter*\"",
      "fields" : ["title", "obj_id"]
    }
  }
}'
```

I'm getting no results back:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : []
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know if you'll be searching only prefixes (i.e. start of words) or any substring of your words?

Comment: any substring, but if solution for this cases are different it would be good to see both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your `title` field has probably been analyzed by the standard analyzer (default setting) and the title `Cor Interface Monitoring` has been tokenized as the three tokens `cor`, `interface` and `monitoring`.

In order to search any substring of words, you need to create a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) which leverages the [ngram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) in order to also index all substrings of each of your tokens.

You can create your index like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/process_test_3 -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "substring_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "substring"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "14": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "substring_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can reindex your data. What this will do is that the title `Cor Interface Monitoring` will now be tokenized as:

- `co`, `cor`, `or`
- `in`, `int`, `inte`, `inter`, `interf`, etc
- `mo`, `mon`, `moni`, etc

so that your second search query will now return the document you expect because the tokens `cor` and `inter` will now match.

Comment: you're right, i've used custom analyzer. with your settings all works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Val's solution. 
Just wanted to add something.
Since your query is relatively simple, you may want to have a look at `match`/`match_phrase` queries. Match queries does have the regex parsing like query_string and are thus lighter.
You can find the details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: match query doesn't interpret the "*" character as a wildcard that is why - query_string

Comment: My solution is only a continuation of Val's solution. You will first need the substring_analyzer as described by Val. After that, you can just carry out the match query. You won't need the * in the beginning and/or end. Match query not interpreting "*" as wildcard is what that makes it faster. Moreover, there is multi_match query, which takes a list of fields like in your original question. So, with the combination of right mapping, match/multi_match query and operator values, you can get the desired behaviour. Use query_string for complex query requiring regex parsing.

Comment: thank for extended answer, now i understand main keys of it and will try. thank you