# PHP Elastic Search Full Text Search - Sort by Relevance

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to fetch "User" data using the "%LIKE%" condition in Elastic Search.

```
GET user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": ["firstname", "lastname"],
            "query": "*a*"
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_score": "desc"
    }
}
```

It returns the results with "_score": 1 for all the data.

The data with name "Kunal Dethe" is first and "Abhijit Pingale" is second.

But as expected "Abhijit Pingale" should come first because, the letter "a" occurs twice in this name and not in "Kunal Dethe".

Any ideas why?

**EDIT:**
Used the "nGram" solution but for a text like "ab", the grams are broken down as "a", "b" then "ab" as the "min_gram" is set to 1 because the result should be returned even when a single character is entered.

But I want the search to be done as "ab" only.

Of course, can increase the "min_gram" but can it be dynamically set to the length of the text searched?

```
POST /user
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "substring": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 15
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "substring_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "substring"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "user": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "firstname": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "substring_analyzer"
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "substring_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Searching via

GET user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": ["firstname^2", "lastname"],
            "query": "ab"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scoring does not make sense when you use wildcards. That's why it's doing that. Also, using a prefix-wildcard is asking for trouble because it _must_ check literally every term in the inverted index.

Comment: But I do need the "\*a\*" like query to be done. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to avoid wildcards, you need a solution involving ngrams. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331249/elasticsearch-query-string-dont-search-by-word-part/34331544#34331544

Comment: Can use nGrams but then when searched as "\*Kunal Dethe\*", I would like it to search as "%Kunal Dethe%" which is full text but without breaking the words into grams.

Comment: Had to implement "min_gram" with 1 as per the requirement. But I need to give a boost/preference to "firstname" field over others.

Comment: you think the first "A" in "Abhijit Pingale" is counted as relevant when searching for "*a*"? (It's not "a*")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of achieving what you want is to specify an analyzer to use (i.e. `standard`) at search time so your input doesn't get analyzed by the default ngram analyzer. That way you'll only match `ab` tokens and neither `a` nor `b` tokens.

```
GET user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": ["firstname^2", "lastname"],
            "query": "ab",
            "analyzer": "standard"     <--- add this
        }
    }
}
```

A better approach, however, is to set `"search_analyzer": "standard"` in your mapping instead of using the ngram approach at search time as well, which is the case when only specifying `"analyzer": "substring_analyzer"`. So if you search for `ab` you'll only match `ab` tokens as that will not be ngram'ed at search time.

```
"mappings": {
    "user": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "firstname": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "substring_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"       <-- add this
            },
            "lastname": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "substring_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"       <-- add this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked well. Thank you. Applied the "mappings" solution.

Comment: I also need a help with one thing.. when searched with "ab ", i.e. with a space, can we get results with "ab" giving higher score and then other results with a "space"?

Comment: The `standard` tokenizer will split on spaces, so you won't have any spaces indexed in your terms. If you want to include spaces in your queries, you need to use an ngram tokenizer instead of ngrams token filters

Comment: I have added the question here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808547/php-elastic-search-filtered-query-string-search`

Comment: Yes, of course. I still got few hours till I can award the bounty. That's why I added a separate question for another issue.

Comment: did you get time to check the other question that I have mentioned in the above comments?

Comment: Yes, I will do soon.