# PHP Elastic Search Filtered Query String Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

All would like to use the filtered query where results should contain data from the "query_string" and also from the "term - filter" applied.

```
GET blog/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": [ "description" ],
                    "query": "a"                 // or just ""
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "topic_id": [
                        10
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is:

1. all blog records having letter "a" or "" in it with topic_id is 10.
2. also rest of the records where topic_id is 10 even if the description is blank/empty.

So final result should be - the matching records with higher score and should come at the top, then the records just matching the "topic_id" from  the filter.

Comment: When searched with "a", I only get data which contains letter "a" in the description, but I need the data with empty("") description with topic_id 10 too. Also when searched with blank(""), not getting any data. But I expect data with empty description with topic_id 10.

Comment: The query I am trying is mentioned in the question.

Comment: this maybe [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561981/find-documents-with-empty-string-value-on-elasticsearch)

Comment: @keety, the link that you gave would not help much as I want both the matches as per the `query` added as well the empty search but with the filter of `topic_id` value. The condition 1 that I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @KunalDethe check my answer. I thinks that is what you are looking for. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is use [muti_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) mapping for `description` field. One of the fields in multi-field should be non-analyzed.
Once the data has been reindexed you can use a simple [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to achieve what you want :

### Example

**Create Index:**

```
put test
{
    "mappings": {
        "data" : {
            "properties": {
                "description" : {
                    "type": "string",
                     "fields": {
                        "raw" : {"type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"}
                     }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
put test/data/1 
{
    "description" : "a",
    "test_id" : 10
}
put test/data/2
{
    "description" : "",
    "test_id" : 10
}

put test/data/3
{
    "description" : "hello",
    "test_id" : 10
}


put test/data/4
{
    "description": "a",
    "test_id" : 20
}
```

**Query:**

```
post test/data/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "disable_coord": "true",
               "should": [
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                           "description"
                        ],
                        "query": "a"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                           "term": {
                              "description.raw": ""
                           }
                        },
                        "boost": 0.2
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                           "exists": {
                              "field": "description"
                           }
                        },
                        "boost": 0.1
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "test_id": [
                  10
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Results :**

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.5113713,
            "_source": {
               "description": "a",
               "test_id": 10
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.29277003,
            "_source": {
               "description": "",
               "test_id": 10
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.097590014,
            "_source": {
               "description": "hello",
               "test_id": 10
            }
         }
      ]
```

Query Empty string:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "disable_coord": "true",
               "should": [
                  {
                     "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                           "description"
                        ],
                        "query": ""
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                           "term": {
                              "description.raw": ""
                           }
                        },
                        "boost": 0.2
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                           "exists": {
                              "field": "description"
                           }
                        },
                        "boost": 0.1
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "terms": {
               "test_id": [
                  10
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Result :

```
  "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.3416407,
            "_source": {
               "description": "",
               "test_id": 10
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.44721356,
            "_source": {
               "description": "a",
               "test_id": 10
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.44721356,
            "_source": {
              "description": "hello",
               "test_id": 10
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: Let me try it out.

Comment: @KunalDethe curious did the above not work as expected ?

Comment: the result that I am getting when search text is empty (""), then only the data with empty description is being returned. But I also want the non-empty to be returned but later in the result. Empty description should take priority over the non-empty.

Comment: just to calrify if you are search for "a" you would like "a" results followed by empty string followed by rest of the documents with non-empty and non-"a" . Similary if you search for empty you like empty followed by non empty  in the results, is that accurate  ?

Comment: Yes, need exactly the same.

Comment: When empty (blank) is searched using the edited answer, it only returns the  documents with empty string only. But I also need the non-empty followed after them.

Comment: it does return the non empty  documents for me see the example in the answer for "Query Empty string" and the result. Which version of elasticsearch do you have ?

Comment: What your solution is doing: When a non-empty string is searched, it returns the non-empty matching values first, then empty and then the non-empty not-matching. But it works well for empty search string and so will use this with an "if" condition. Separate query for empty and non-empty search string. Thank you for all your help. Glad it finally worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query? Check this query it will work fine for you.

**all blog records having letter "a" in it with topic_id is 10.**

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "in": {
          "topic_id": [
            "10"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "query": {
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "query": {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "description": {
                          "value": "*a*"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Also rest of the records where topic_id is 10 even if the description is blank/empty. This will return all the other records that doesn't match the wildcard.**

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "in": {
          "topic_id": [
            "10"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "query": {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "description": {
                            "value": "*a*"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**To find only the empty " " description fields with topic_id 10. try this,**

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "in": {
          "topic_id": [
            "10"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "query": {
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "script": {
                "script": "_source.description.length() == 0"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For ES 2.x**

Using a `bool` query should do the trick.

Here's the query I will use:

```
GET blog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [ "description" ],
              "query": "a"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "topic_id": [
              10
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the `should` clause of the bool query will tell Elassticsearch that document matching the `query_string` should be returned. In the `query_string` consider using wildcards if you want to match any document containing `a`. 
For example `"query_string": { "query": "*a*" }`

The `must` clause in the other hand will tell that, for considering the document a valid match, it must contain `10` in the `topic_id` field. Wether the `should` clause could or could not match.

[Bool filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/combining-filters.html#bool-filter)

I hope this could help you.