# Elasticsearch NEST: partial/full-text search without wildcard

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I want to have a search engine for my users. Let's say user class is:

```
public class User
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have such users in my db:

```
(1) new User { Code = "XW1234", Name = "John Doe" }, 
(2) new User { Code = "AD4567", Name = "Jane Doe" }
```

So:
When my query is: "doe" (mind the lowercase) I want to see (1) and (2)
When my query is: "4" I want to see (1) and (2)
When my query is: "x" I want to see (1)
When my query is: "ja" I want to see (2)
I want to work similarly as `like %doe%` in SQL. Please don't mind queries length - I will use 3 letters minimum. This is just an example.

I have a solution with wildcards - works but performance is poor.

I was trying to configure index to use ngram tokenizer but no success - I was receiving an empty collection.

I also checked this ("starts with" approach): 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html
No success.

Please provide the C# code. I don't know if I'm translating the Elastic search jsons correctly.

**EDIT** 
According to the first comment I tried this:

```
private const string DefaultIndexName = "test";
private const string ElasticSearchServerUri = @"http://192.168.99.100:32769";

private static readonly IndexName UsersIndexName = "users";

public IElasticClient CreateElasticClient()
{
    var settings = CreateConnectionSettings();

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var studentsIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(UsersIndexName)
        .Mappings(ms => ms
            .Map<User>(m => m
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.Code)
                        .Analyzer("substring_analyzer")))));
    client.CreateIndex(UsersIndexName, descriptor => studentsIndexDescriptor
        .Settings(s => s
            .Analysis(a => a
                .Analyzers(analyzer => analyzer
                    .Custom("substring_analyzer", analyzerDescriptor => analyzerDescriptor.Tokenizer("standard").Filters("lowercase", "substring")))
                .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                    .NGram("substring", filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor.MinGram(2).MaxGram(15))))));

    return client;
}

private static ConnectionSettings CreateConnectionSettings()
{
    var uri = new Uri(ElasticSearchServerUri);
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri);
    settings
        .DefaultIndex(DefaultIndexName);

    return settings;
}
```

And I used this query:

```
public IEnumerable<User> Search(string query)
{
    var result = elasticClient.Search<User>(descriptor => descriptor
        .Query(q => q
            .QueryString(queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor.Query(query).Fields(fs => fs.Fields(f1 => f1.Code)))));
    return result.Documents;
}
```

Didn't work.

I tried Codes: "1234" and "5678". I tried to query with "23", "5" - no results.
When I search for "1234" - it returns the correct user.

Comment: You need to use an ngram token filter. This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331249/elasticsearch-query-string-dont-search-by-word-part/34331544#34331544

Comment: _"Please provide the C# code"_. What have you tried so far? Can you show your attempt with an NGram tokenizer / NGram token filter?

Comment: @RussCam - I added an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect within your code:

1. When indexing the users, you do not specify the `users` index and so the users are indexed into the default index.
2. When searching, you do not specify the `users` index and so will be querying against the default index, `test`. This index contains the indexed documents, however the `code` field is not analyzed with the `substring_analyzer` because this analysis is defined in the `users` index.

NEST provides a configuration option on `ConnectionSettings`, `.InferMappingFor<T>()`, to associate a particualr POCO type with a particular index name; this index will be used if one is not specified on the request and takes precedence over the default index.

```
var uri = new Uri(ElasticSearchServerUri);
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri)
    .DefaultIndex(DefaultIndexName)
    .InferMappingFor<User>(d => d
        .IndexName(UsersIndexName)
    );
```

The rest of of your code is correct. Here's a complete working example

```
private const string DefaultIndexName = "test";
private const string ElasticSearchServerUri = @"http://localhost:9200";
private const string UsersIndexName = "users";

void Main()
{
    var client = CreateElasticClient();

    var users = new[] {
        new User { Code = "XW1234", Name = "John Doe" },
        new User { Code = "AD4567", Name = "Jane Doe" }
    };

    client.IndexMany(users);

    // refresh the index after indexing so that the documents are immediately 
    // available for search. This is good for testing, 
    // but avoid doing it in production.
    client.Refresh(UsersIndexName);

    var result = client.Search<User>(descriptor => descriptor
        .Query(q => q
            .QueryString(queryDescriptor => queryDescriptor
                .Query("1234")
                .Fields(fs => fs
                    .Fields(f1 => f1.Code)
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // outputs 1
    Console.WriteLine(result.Total);
}

public class User
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public IElasticClient CreateElasticClient()
{
    var settings = CreateConnectionSettings();
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    // this is here so that the example can be re-run.
    // Remove this!
    if (client.IndexExists(UsersIndexName).Exists)
    {
        client.DeleteIndex(UsersIndexName);
    }

    client.CreateIndex(UsersIndexName, descriptor => descriptor
        .Mappings(ms => ms
            .Map<User>(m => m
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.Code)
                        .Analyzer("substring_analyzer")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .Settings(s => s
            .Analysis(a => a
                .Analyzers(analyzer => analyzer
                    .Custom("substring_analyzer", analyzerDescriptor => analyzerDescriptor
                        .Tokenizer("standard")
                        .Filters("lowercase", "substring")
                    )
                )
                .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                    .NGram("substring", filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor
                        .MinGram(2)
                        .MaxGram(15)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    return client;
}

private static ConnectionSettings CreateConnectionSettings()
{
    var uri = new Uri(ElasticSearchServerUri);
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri)
        .DefaultIndex(DefaultIndexName)
        .InferMappingFor<User>(d => d
            .IndexName(UsersIndexName)
        );

    return settings;
}
```