# Elastic search index on string ngram?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Say I have a document containing the below sentence

```
    This is Elastic search learning example
```

Now if I type `tic` i need to search engine to return document containing `Elastic` word. My question does  elastic search() build index on
all ngram of  word in advance while storing the document or We need to tell the search server to build the index on all ngram using custom
tokenizer ?

Does ES keeps all index in file by default(understanding based on https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-dive-into-elasticsearch-storage) ? Can we configure it to keep it in memory only  or both in memory and DB ?

Comment: anagram is something different, what you need is ngram. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331249/elasticsearch-query-string-dont-search-by-word-part/34331544#34331544

Comment: @val . Thanks corrected it.

Comment: ok, the proposed solution should suit your need

Comment: You mean We need to tell the search server to build the index on all ngram using custom tokenizer ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, otherwise ES will simply analyze your string with the standard analyzer which tokenizes on whitespaces and punctuation.

Comment: ok makes sesnse. Can you please provide inputs on second part of question also i.e. if index are kept in file or memory ?