# Partial multi-field search elastic search

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, search, indexing

I'm trying to setup a mapping + query that matches multiple fields and the following requirements:

We have videos in our application, and we index the following fields: `localizedTitle`, `localizedDescription` and `localizedKeywords`

Example video:

```js
{
  "_id": "5b7d02e023366c0d85cb05d8",
  "localizedTitle": [
    {
      "language": "en-GB",
      "value": "Test String"
    },
    {
      "language": "nl",
      "value": "Test String - In het nederlands"
    }
  ],
  "localizedDescription": [
    {
      "language": "en-GB",
      "value": "Test Description"
    }
  ],
  "localizedTags": [
    {
      "value": [
        "tag in nederlands"
      ],
      "language": "nl"
    }
  ]
}
```

The requirements are:

A video with the title "Test String"

Should be returned if the user searches for:

- "Test"
- "Tes"
- "rin"
- "ing"
- "st st"

We only use `'type': 'text'` in the mapping fields, so nothing special there.

This is the query we currently use:

```js
  const query = {
    from: (page * perPage),
    size: perPage,
    query: {
      bool: {
        filter,
        must: {
          multi_match: {
            query: queryString,
            fields: [
              'localizedTitle.value',
              'localizedDescription.value',
              'localizedTags.value'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Running our test suite, we end up with some requirements met but the partial word searching is not working correctly:

```js
  GET /videos/search
    Search
      ✓ should respond with a result when searched for: Test (69ms)
      ✓ should respond with a result when searched for: Test Test (60ms)
      ✓ should respond with a result when searched for: test test (58ms)
      ✓ should respond with a result when searched for: Test st (54ms)
      ✓ should respond with a result when searched for: st Test (56ms)
      x) should respond with a result when searched for: Tes
      x) should respond with a result when searched for: rin
      x) should respond with a result when searched for: ing
      x) should respond with a result when searched for: st st
```

What we have tried:

- Playing around with `Fuzziness`, set to `AUTO` or a `numeric value (0 - 3)` but this gave us inconsistent test results, and seem to result in the same result set as above.
- Using a Regex (but from our research, this it not a scalable solution in terms of performance)

Any suggestions are more than welcome

Comment: you're looking for ngrams, this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331249/elasticsearch-query-string-dont-search-by-word-part/34331544#34331544

Comment: @Val I've tried your answer, with the exact same settings, but it now just returns everything indexed...