# Elasticsearch wildcard usage

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

### Problem

When running a query using wildcards on elasticsearch expected results are not being returned.

To replicate the issue:

Version 5.5.1

### Create an index

PUT /example-test/

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "Change": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "searchProperties": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Add a document to the index

POST /example-test/Change/01_MEP_01

```
{
  "id": "01_MEP_01",  
  "searchProperties": [
    {
      "key": "a.x",
      "value": "You take the red pill you stay in Wonderland, and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Observe document in index

GET /example-test/Change/_search

### Run a query

POST /example-test/Change/_search

```
{      
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [        
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "you ta",
            "default_operator": "and",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "fields": [
              "_all"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

From here on I'll just specify the "query" portion of the query. I've run this for several examples:

```
+-------------------+-------+
|       Query       | Found |
+-------------------+-------+
| you ta            | false |
| you ta*           | true  |
| you take*         | true  |
| land              | false |
| *land*            | true  |
| *land,*           | false |
| *land,            | false |
| wonderland        | true  |
| wonderland,       | true  |
| wonderlan*,       | false |
| \\*wonderland,\\* | true  |
+-------------------+-------+
```

Note - in the last example the backslashes before the wildcard are added (possibly in error) from reading the docs here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) where it is stated:

> Another option is to provide the wildcard fields search in the query string itself (properly escaping the * sign)

Is this just when specifying field names in the query?

### Question

If I want to allow my users to search for "land" and return the document (as it contains the word "wonderland,") how would I need to use wildcards to return my document?

### Further information

It would appear the comma is causing an issue here. This seems odd. View the tokens generated by running:

POST /example-test/_analyze

```
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": "You take the red pill you stay in Wonderland, and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes"
}
```

We can see "Wonderland," results in the token "wonderland". My understanding is the query will flow through the same analyser (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html), so should result in the same token? It appears this is not the case?

Comment: The problem is that you're searching on a nested field and `query_string` doesn't work well on nested data

Comment: Can you please define "doesn't work well"? I need something a bit more deterministic

Comment: As in, it is not implemented yet and [still being](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322) [worked on](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16551)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a read over

Comment: Pretty sure you can still get away by using a nested query and then either a `wildcard` query (beware of performance!) or properly analyze your data to [index ngrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331249/elasticsearch-query-string-dont-search-by-word-part/34331544#34331544) and search for part of words.