# Elasticsearch: suffix search by query string in multiple fields

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm looking for a way to perform a phrase search on multiple fields, and be able to use the asterisk (*) wildcard character for both prefix and suffix search.

Here's my example:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
      "query": "mycity mystreet mynumber",
      "default_operator": "AND", 
      "fields":     [ "city", "street", "number"]
    }
  }
}
```

I used AND as the default operator, because I want **each** word in the query string to be found in **any** of the specified fields.

When I test above three-word phrase, it matches records that contain the three words in any of mentioned three fields.

I can also use an asterisk to perform a prefix search, e.g.: *myc* mystreet mynumber*, but I want to be able to perform suffix search as well, e.g. **city mystreet mynumber*. But *simple_query_string* does not support that.

When I use *query_string* instead, I can achieve what I want if it comes to suffix search, but multi-field search stops working as before. Namely, all words have to be found in one of listed fields to match the criteria.

To conclude, I need to be able to search in multiple fields (every word in the phrase has to match any listed field), with prefix or suffix. And I need the search to be fast... Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You need to leverage ngrams. See a solution that worked for me here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666371/4604579 (look for `my_ngram_analyzer`)

Comment: Thank you for the link, but after a short analysis I think that it does not solve my problem. That solution seems to be based on an assumption that I know in advance whether I search by an affix or by a substring, and based on that I choose one of the fields (e.g. text.ends_with). What I need is a solution that accepts a phrase like *suffix and is able to interpret it correctly, without my need to parse it by myself to decide how to search. Unless this is the only solution...

Comment: What the link shows is that by analyzing your input using ngrams, you end up indexing prefixes, infixes and suffixes. Then you can search for anything and a match will come up wherever that input matches within the string. Another useful answer that shows this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34331544/4604579

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning Elasticsearch. I created the substring_analyzer as in the example, with a substring filter, and defined a field like this: "city": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "substring_analyzer"}. Search behavior is now a bit awkward. It finds almost every phrase I type, as if it searched for single characters of that phrase. I guess I missed something. What type of query should I use with fields defined this way?

Comment: You use the substring analyzer only when indexing your content, when searching you should still use the standard analyzer to make sure the search input doesn't get tokenized as well.

Comment: The more time I spend on it, the more I understand. Thank you for your assistance. Seems that I achieved what I needed. You were right that I had to specify the standard analyzer for search, because otherwise the phrase underwent tokenization.

Comment: So now I understand that the substring analyzer generates substrings that include prefixes and suffixes (so there is no need to define the two latter as well). At my first glance I rejected your first suggestion, because I didn't understand the topic well enough. Sorry! :)

Comment: Still, however, simple_query_string allows using an asterisk, which I should consider switching off, as it seems to be no longer necessary. I still can't use a phrase like '*wordending', but I can use 'wordending'. It's fine!

Comment: I have a question, if you don't mind. If I don't specify an analyzer explicitly for a query, what analyzer is used then? Is it the same analyzer as the one associated with a field being searched (so that the field and the phrase are analyzed the same way) or is it some default analyzer for all fields included in search?